# RED HAT BRMS installation error on EAP7

Tags: jboss7.x, drools, redhat

While installing 'jboss-brms-6.3.0.GA-installer.jar' on my EAP 7.0 ('jboss-eap-7.0.0-installer.jar') I am getting error in BRMS installation wizard as below.

```
The provided EAP installation is missing the following required files:
\standalone\configuration\standalone-osgi.xml
```

'standalone-osgi.xml' didn't come along with EAP 7 installation.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: note that EAP 7 is not jboss 7.x. EAP 7 is based on wildfly, which is JBoss AS 8+ equivalent. For more details see [this](https://videos.cdn.redhat.com/summit2015/presentations/12186_red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform-7-roadmap-new-features.pdf) (slide 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Red Hat BRMS 6 supported configuration](https://access.redhat.com/articles/705183#Support_6_3)s :

Application Containers  Version
JBoss EAP   6.4.(7+)

I understand 6.4.(7+) as *any server of the 6.4.X branch, starting from the 6.4.7*. To my understanding, this does exclude EAP 7. There is a chance BRMS can be installed on EAP 7, but probably with the manual ZIP install, not with the automatic installer.

Moreover, if you are trying to install BRMS, you probably have enterprise support from Red Hat. Running BRMS 6.3 on EAP 7 may exclude your support.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

From Redhat JBoss BPM Suite installation Guide: [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.4/html-single/installation_guide/#sect_the_red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite_installer_installation)

**Section 2.1:** This section describes the steps required to install Red Hat JBoss BPM Suite using the JAR file installer installation method. The JAR file is an executable file that installs Red Hat JBoss BPM Suite on an existing Red Hat JBoss EAP 6 installation.
However, ***the JAR installer does not support Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.0. For Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.0, only Deployable Zip installation option is supported.***

So to install BPM/BRMS on EAP 7 You have 2 use the ZIP file.
EAP download page [link](https://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/download/).

You can find the steps required for installing with ZIP